# Installing TA-lib on Python3 (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, anaconda, ta-lib

I am trying to install TA-lib on my Windows 10 PC, but it is trying to downgrade a lot of the packages to 2.7 (I think).

I have the Anaconda distribution of Python 3.7 installed. I am installing it using `"conda install -c quantopian ta-lib"`. When I run it it in the Anaconda prompt, it tries to downgrade a lot of my packages, seemingly from 3.7 to 2.7. Will this stop me from using Python 3.7 correctly?

Here are some of the packages it is trying to downgrade (removed a lot of them), including Python, numpy, jupyter etc.

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

> anaconda-client                              1.7.2-py37_0 -->
>   1.7.2-py27_0
>
> anaconda-navigator                           1.9.6-py37_0 -->
>   1.8.4-py27_0
>
> anaconda-project                             0.8.2-py37_0 -->
>   0.8.2-py27_0
>
> ipykernel                            5.1.0-py37h39e3cac_0 -->
>   4.10.0-py27_0
>
> ipython                              7.2.0-py37h39e3cac_0 -->
>   5.8.0-py27_0
>
> ipython_genutils                             0.2.0-py37_0 --> 0.2.0-
>   py27hbe997df_0
>
> ipywidgets                                   7.4.2-py37_0 -->
>   7.4.2-py27_0
>
> itsdangerous                                 1.1.0-py37_0 -->
>   1.1.0-py27_0
>
> jdcal                                          1.4-py37_0 -->
>   1.4-py27_0
>
> jupyter                                      1.0.0-py37_7 -->
>   1.0.0-py27_7
>
> jupyter_client                               5.2.4-py37_0 -->
>   5.2.4-py27_0
>
> jupyter_console                              6.0.0-py37_0 -->
>   5.2.0-py27_1
>
> jupyter_core                                 4.4.0-py37_0 -->
>   4.4.0-py27_0
>
> jupyterlab                                  0.35.3-py37_0 -->
>   0.33.11-py27_0
>
> numpy                               1.15.4-py37h19fb1c0_0 -->
>   1.11.3- py27h239e66a_12
>
> numpy-base                          1.15.4-py37hc3f5095_0 -->
>   1.11.3- py27hb1d0314_12
>
> pandas                              0.23.4-py37h830ac7b_0 -->
>   0.23.4- py27h39f3610_0
>
> pandas-datareader                            0.7.0-py37_0 -->
>   0.7.0-py27_0
>
> pickleshare                                  0.7.5-py37_0 -->
>   0.7.5-py27_0
>
> pytest-arraydiff                       0.3-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 0.3-
>   py27h39e3cac_0
>
> pytest-astropy                               0.5.0-py37_0 -->
>   0.5.0-py27_0
>
> pytest-remotedata                            0.3.1-py37_0 -->
>   0.3.1-py27_0
>
> python                                   3.7.1-h8c8aaf0_6 -->
>   2.7.16-hcb6e200_0

I'd like to be able to run TA-lib without having to downgrade to Python 2. Is it possible?

Comment: `Will this stop me from using Python 3.7 correctly?` - yes unfortunately. It seems the channel you are using only provides versions for python <= 3.5. See https://anaconda.org/Quantopian/ta-lib/files. Your options are (a) using pip for installing (b) updating the recipe for python > 3.5 and submitting to conda-forge (https://github.com/conda-forge/staged-recipes)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go!